# Diagnosing app's dynamic code downloading

Tags: android, malware, libs

An app I published in Google Play got flagged by Google as being in breach of their malicious behavior policy. Specifically they stated that: “Your app contains the following dynamic code downloading: https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/appdatasearch/libAppDataSearchExt_armeabi_v7a.v7.so”

I was completely unaware of this behavior and would like to remedy the situation. However, even after a few days researching this subject online, I still have no idea how to locate the root cause and fix it.

The google play support team can’t or won’t give any more information/guidance other than the statement above.

I suspect this behavior could stem from one of the external libraries used in the project (since I don’t perform this action directly in my code), but have yet to find the way to check this hypothesis

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?
Any diagnosis tools that monitor this sort of behavior by an app?

Thank You,

Comment: There is an app named Packet capture you can use it to drill down to at least what point in your app is invoking this request.

Comment: This domain is owned by Google itself, hahaha

Comment: It might help if you could point to the code of your app (Github, GitLab, …) or, if that's not an option, at least name those "external libraries" used in your project.